# Xamarin Forms app crashing on macOS when MainPage changed

Tags: xamarin.forms

Application is crashing when MainPage is changed with below error.

`Failed to marshal the Objective-C object 0x7feb16e40d90 (type: Xamarin_Forms_Platform_MacOS_LayoutRenderer). Could not find an existing managed instance for this object, nor was it possible to create a new managed instance (because the type 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.MacOS.LayoutRenderer' does not have a constructor that takes one IntPtr argument).`

Code written to navigate

`Application.Current.MainPage = new QueuePage();`

When I installed Visual Studio and XCode same package works without any issue.

Comment: Please do not post duplicates.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67823895/xamarin-mac-application-crashes-with-error-xamarin-forms-platform-macos-layoutre

Comment: What does your code look like, it is possible that you need to set up such a constructor yourself.

Comment: *"When I installed Visual Studio and XCode same package works without any issue."* - I don't understand. If it works when you install those, then what is the problem?

Comment: You need to *show the code* that causes the problem. Show the minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem. I have no idea what "when MainPage is changed" means. Show code that creates a **simple** MainPage, then the code that attempts to "change MainPasge'. Start with a blank page if possible - does "changing" it still crash?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, on client machine we will not have Visual Studio or XCode installed, that time it application will not work. When we install VS & XCode to debug check what is the issue it worked. Problem here we cannot ask all users to install VS & XCode to use our application. I have added code line causing issue.

Comment: First, make sure it is a `Release` build. If that doesn't work, then you need to prepare it for "Publishing". As if you were going to send it to Apple Store - but you don't actually upload it. Make a `Release` build. Then follow instructions [Publishing Xamarin.Mac Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/deploy-test/publishing-to-the-app-store/) through page [Signing Xamarin.Mac Apps with a Developer ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/deploy-test/publishing-to-the-app-store/signing). You should be able to copy the result to other Macs.

Comment: If there is still a problem (or you already followed those Publishing steps), then we need to isolate exactly what is causing the problem. Instead of changing to `QueuePage`, use Visual Studio menu to Add a new Content Page, call it `TestPage`. Don't change its contents - leave the sample contents (or maybe it is blank). Do `Application.Current.MainPage = new TestPage();`.  Does it crash or work?

Comment: The above suggestions assumed you copied the app to another Mac to test it. Maybe I misunderstood. Are you running Visual Studio, and then doing "Debug" to run the app? If so, then even when "it works", Debug Output panel might show some error or warning message when `Application.Current.MainPage = new QueuePage();` is executed. Put a breakpoint on that line. When breakpoint is hit, "Step Over" it. Does that put some message in Output pane?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, it is release build, but not published on store as of now. Navigation happening correctly everywhere in application, except one place. That too worked when installed VS & XCode. May be I need to recheck my publish settings. Thanks

Comment: OK. I did not know that navigation was working for other pages. It would be best to find out exactly what about `QueuePage` causes the problem. One approach would be to comment out most of the XAML (and any special code behind methods), see if it navigates to that page when it is just an empty (blank) page. Then start adding back in the elements on the page, until it crashes.